# Selenium xpath : Finding first table in the tables list

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, phantomjs

Here is selenium xpath codes to get the first table from the tables having class "table".

```
List<WebElement> tables = driver.findElements(By
                        .xpath("//table[@class='table'][1]//td[1]/a"));
```

It is returning the first td's which is correct but it is returning from all the tables where as I need only first table.

Here is the markup.

[image]

Comment: Try using the xpath with a slight change : `List<WebElement> tables = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//table[@class='table'])[1]/td[1]/a"` (removed a double slash after table)

Comment: @nullpointer Thank you :) Yours and the answerer solutions both are working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be sure only the first table selected, use parens around `table` selector before applying the index predicate :

```
List<WebElement> tables = driver.findElements(By
                        .xpath("(//table[@class='table'])[1]//td[1]/a"));
```

Comment: Hmm..nothing changed when I use this regex. The same results coming in :(

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ that is XPath not regex. Anyway, I'm 100% about the XPath. I couldn't think of anyway such expression can select from other than the first table...

Comment: Here is [a demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/4bf302bb3327f3adfda53c9ae8e7fe0c) which correctly returns from the first table only. If you remove parens around `//table`, it will return from both tables. If you could come up with HTML/XML that demonstrate the problem, I might be able to help further

Comment: Thanks for helping har. Added a pic. That is my markup.